# Why PDO options start with backslashes?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I recently have seen this PDO article:

[image: phpbestpractices.org]

- Is it mandatory?
- Is it a good practice to add a backslash (e.g. \PDO) to each option in the array?
- In which cases it is correct to put a backslash?
- Are there cases where it is bad to put them?
- I know java packages are point separated `javax.crypto.Cipher`. Is this the same as PHP backslashes?

Comment: it's related to namespacing

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php